# Select HTML node only when it has no class

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack to grab a bunch of a tags. Some of the have 1 of several classes assigned and some have no class. It's those with no class that I need to grab.

I know that to grab a node by class we can do something like;

```
.SelectNodes("//table[@class=\"pagelinks\"]");
```

Similarly you can choose to ignore specific classes or id's with;

```
.SelectNodes("//table[not(@class=\"pagelinks\")]");
```

But is there a way to only grab a node when and only when it has no class?

Comment: Before your edit, your second example was `.SelectNodes("//table[not(@class)]");`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath will select tables that either have no `class` attribute, or that have a `class` attribute that is entirely whitespace (or blank):

```
//table[not(normalize-space(@class))]
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code should select when there's no class attribute defined at all:

```
.SelectNodes("//table[not(@class)]");
```

Comment: Really? interesting. Ill give that a try.